# incrementing array corresponding with a sorting time

Tags: python

I want to create a table with a specific array increments corresponding to that specific time. for example:

```
n     sec
100    0.2
200    0.4
etc..
```

Y is number of tries of specific array, n is the array size, increment is specific increment

```
if sortfunction==1:
            i=0
            while i<y:
                dt=0
                for i in range(n):
                    i=i+increment
                    dt+=sort_timehelp(x,quick_sort)
                    output="%d %f\n" %(i,dt)
                    print output
```

for example if i put N as 1000 and increment 100, then it would look something like an above table.

right now i get:

```
n    sec
100  0.001
101  0.0012
102  0.0014
```

etc it goes by 1 not by the increment size

EDIT:
I got another question: why this does this while loop doesn't go more times?

```
   i=0
   while i<y:
        i=i+1
        dt=0
        for i in xrange(increment, n+increment, increment):
                dt+=sort_timehelp(x, quick_sort)
                output="%d %f\n" %(i,dt)
                print output
```

i is the number of array tests.
Why it doesn't go for example 2 times

Edit: Never mind I used for loop instead.
I have a last question.
What if I have a lot of those kinds of if statements only the difference is a sortfunction, then how can i save it all of that stuff to a file, since when I tried it will only save a last printed statement

```
#
 saving=input("You want to save data ? type 0 to continue or 1 to save " )
 if saving == 0:
        continue
 if saving == 1:
        ask=raw_input("Type the name file: ")
        fileout=open(ask+".csv","a")
        fileout.write(output)
        fileout.close()
```

the indentation of "saving" is the same as if sortfunction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The range(n) function returns a list [0,1,2,...], which the for loop then iterates over.  So when i is 0 and your do `i=i+increment`, your value of i (100) gets thrown away, and replaced with the next element of the list - i.e. 1.

You can instead try `for i in range(increment,n+increment,increment)`, and then delete the first line inside your for block.  The range function itself will add `increment` every iteration of the loop - i.e. i will be 100,200,300,...,1000

Comment: +1, I hadn't really noticed the `i` was being reused as the loop variable, but my understanding is that there should be `n` iterations. Also it's not clear how changing the way `i` works will affect the `i<y` test

Comment: I forgot to mention the while part.  It will probably either have no effect or cause an infinite loop, depending on the size of y, since the value of i will be the same at the end of the for loop no matter what - `n-1+increment` in the original poster's question, or n in my version

Comment: And yes, there will be n iterations, but the actual value returned by range is being used in each iteration - so he's taking 0+increment, 1+increment, 2+increment, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in xrange(increment, (n+1)*increment, increment):
    dt+=sort_timehelp(x,quick_sort)
    output="%d %f\n" %(i,dt)
    print output
```